# What is the difference between these mondaic functions?

Tags: haskell, monads

So I have these two functions:

```
filterM _ [] = []
filterM p (x:xs) = do
                  n <- p x
                  ys <- filterM p xs
                  return (if n then x:ys else x:xs)
```

and

```
filterM _ [] = return []
filterM p (x:xs) = do
                  n <- p x
                  ys <- filterM p xs
                  return (if n then x:ys else x:xs)
```

Resulting in these results for the following input: `filterM (\x -> [True,False]) [0..3]`

```
[]
```

or

```
[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]
```

Why does `return` impact the execution so much?

Comment: `return []` means in the context of a list `[[]]`, this is necessary for `ys`, since if we return `[]`, then `ys` "does not take a value", hence the result will be an empty list as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh of course. `return` wraps the value into the monad. This one being derived from the `[]` monad and as such resulting in `[]` being wrapped in `[]`

Comment: Writing a type signature is strongly recommended to avoid these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us look at a simple case where we call:

```
filterM (const [True, False]) [0]
```

We expect that this will return `[[0], [0]]`. If we take a look at the first implementation, we see that this will result in:

```
filterM (const [True, False]) (0:[]) = do
    n <- [True, False]
    ys <- filterM (const [True, False]) []
    return (if n then 0:ys else 0:[])
```

If we take the first implementation, the the `filterM (const [True, False]) []` will result in `[]`. So this means that it will look like:

```
-- first implementation
filterM (const [True, False]) (0:[]) = do
    n <- [True, False]
    ys <- []
    return (if n then 0:ys else 0:[])
```

Since for the `instance Monad []`, [the **`>>=`** is implemented as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1133):

> ```
> instance Monad [] where
>     return x = [x]
>     xs >>= f = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
> ```

this thus means that if `xs` is empty, then the result will be emtpy as well.

In the second implementation, `return []` will result in `[[]]`, so a *singleton list* where the single element is an empty list. In that case, it thus looks like:

```
-- second implementation
filterM (const [True, False]) (0:[]) = do
    n <- [True, False]
    ys <- [[]]
    return (if n then 0:ys else 0:[])
```

This thus means that we enumerate over the list, and `ys` will take the value `[]`, so it will result in a list `[[0], [0]]`.

Normally the filter will however not prepend `x` in both cases, furthermore you probably want to yield `x:ys` and `ys`; not `x:ys` and `x:xs`. A correct implementation is thus:

```
filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM _ [] = return []
filterM p (x:xs) = do
    n <- p x
    ys <- filterM p xs
    return (if n then x:ys else ys)
```